# Sending email to user upon registration in react

Tags: javascript, email, reactjs

I am working on an app with React as the base. I have created a registration page and want to send a verification code via email to the user once he registers. I have done the UI part, but have no idea on how to proceed and make it work. I have seen how emails are sent to the user upon registration in PHP, and want to implement the same in React.

Comment: You cannot send email from React, you need to send it from backend server(e.g. Node, PHP, Java, .Net, etc.)

Comment: How can i implement the same? Can you show me a demo if possible?

Comment: If you want help with backend code, you need to at least say what backend you are using (is it PHP? because you mention PHP. So I think it's PHP)

Comment: No.. i am not using PHP. Is it possible using Node?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using node, you'll be able to make use of the **node mailer** package. This allows you to send emails easily straight from node.

https://nodemailer.com/

Have a look at there site for all the details on how to get it setup!

Here is some psuedo code:

```
User.register(userDetails).then( (createdUser) => {
    // Your user is created
    // Now lets send them an email

    var mailOptions = {
        from: '"Info ?" <yoursite@yoursite.com>', // sender address
        to: userDetails.email, // This can also contain an array of emails
        subject: 'Thanks for registering with <your site name>', 
        // text: 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
        html: '<b>Some HTML here....</b>' // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    });
})
```